# flutter-mapbox-gl App Drawer opens behind the MapBox :(

Tags: flutter, mapbox, flutter-mapbox-gl

I have the MapBox in one of my routes in my Flutter App. But for some reason it seems to be the topmost control - because it covers the drawer.

How can I get MapBox to be behind the Main App Drawer?

Related Github Issue [here](https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1083)

[image]

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706], locale en-NZ)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

```yaml
environment: 
  sdk: '>=2.17.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  collection:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.3
  get: ^4.6.3
  http:
  logger: ^1.1.0
  mapbox_gl: ^0.16.0
  oauth2_client: ^2.4.0
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^20.1.57

dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test: 
    sdk: flutter

flutter: 
  uses-material-design: true
```

`map.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_gl/mapbox_gl.dart';

import '../services/item.dart';

class MapControl extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapControl({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MapControlState();
}

class MapControlState extends State<MapControl> {
  final itemService = Get.find<ItemService>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  MapboxMapController? mapController;

  _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  _onStyleLoadedCallback() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: const Text("Style loaded :)"),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: MapboxMap(
          styleString: MapboxStyles.LIGHT,
          accessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0)),
          onStyleLoadedCallback: _onStyleLoadedCallback,
        ));
  }
}
```

`view_view.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../common/calendar.dart';
import '../../../common/list.dart';
import '../../../common/map.dart';
import '../../../models/items.dart';
import '../controllers/view_controller.dart';

class ViewView extends GetView<ViewController> {
  const ViewView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Obx(
          () => getView(controller.itemService.currentActiveViewItem.value)),
    );
  }

  Widget getView(Item? viewItem) {
    switch (viewItem?.type?.name) {
      case "CalendarView":
        return const CalendarControl();
      case "ListView":
        return const ListControl();
      case "MapView":
        return const MapControl();
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

`home_view.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:realnet_app/app/common/nav_drawer.dart';

import '../../../common/realnet_icon.dart';
import '../controllers/home_controller.dart';

class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                RealNetIcon(controller.itemService.currentItem.value),
                Text(
                    controller.itemService.currentItem.value?.name ?? "RealNet")
              ],
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: Navigator(
            key: Get.nestedKey(1),
            initialRoute: '/empty',
            onGenerateRoute: controller.onGenerateRoute,
          ),
          drawer: NavDrawer(),
          bottomNavigationBar:
              controller.itemService.currentViewItems.value.length >= 2
                  ? BottomNavigationBar(
                      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                      currentIndex:
                          controller.itemService.currentActiveViewIndex.value,
                      onTap: (value) {
                        controller.itemService.updateActiveViewIndex(value);
                      },
                      items: [
                        ...controller.itemService.currentViewItems.value
                            .map((viewItem) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                                  label: viewItem.name,
                                  icon: RealNetIcon(viewItem),
                                )),
                      ],
                    )
                  : null,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: have you found the answer yet? actually we're facing same problem. the drawer is actually above the map but it's partially invisible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73300884/flutter-mapbox-cause-all-widgets-above-the-map-become-invisible

Comment: yes, it seems flutter 3 broke it and we have to wait for flutter 3.3 to get it fixed on Android :( see https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1041

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!!

try to to move to latest version of flutter, do:

- flutter channel main
- flutter upgrade