# Flutter - Mapbox cause all widgets above the map become invisible

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android

I replaced Google Map with [Mapbox](https://pub.dev/documentation/mapbox_gl) before found out that everything above the map disappeared, which does not happen with Google's. The widgets are all there not gone but they're invisible. Same with popup. I don't think there are setting's option provided by Mapbox since this is not something supposed to happen, like a bug. I don't know but I need to solve it.

```
  MapboxMap map = MapboxMap(
        compassEnabled : false,
        rotateGesturesEnabled : false,
        tiltGesturesEnabled : false,
        minMaxZoomPreference : MinMaxZoomPreference(5, 15),
        initialCameraPosition : CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(0, 0),
              zoom: 15
        ),
        onMapCreated : (MapboxMapController controller){
              completer.complete(controller);
        },
  );
  ...
  Container wrap = Container(... child : map);
  Positioned mark = Positioned(... child: Icon(Icons.location_pin ...) ...);
  Stack stack = Stack(children : [wrap, mark]);
```

Updated :  It's fine on Vivo model. Persistent on Galaxy and Xiaomi

Comment: make sure your widgets in stack are proper indexed, your map should be below and other widget should be at top, [map, widget1, widget2, widget3] like this

Comment: Try wrapping MapBox in a container and giving it a certain height and width

Comment: @Shanu i did...

Comment: @stackunderflow if my idea does not work then try giving height and width to your widgets

Comment: @Jaydeepchatrola i did and doesn't work either

Comment: Flutter 3 broke it and we have to wait for Flutter 3.3 to get it fixed on Android https://github.com/flutter-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/1041

Comment: @Christine thank you very much for your answer. and thank you for flutter team too for the showstopping issue :D

Answer (score 2):

change to channel main , in main this issue is fixed

- flutter channel main
- flutter upgrade

Example :

[image]

in this example you can see

- The app bar
- Positioned icon in the Center of the map
- Positioned bottom widget

all inside the stack widget

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.1.0-0.0.pre.2592 • 
channel main • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Tools • Dart 2.19.0
```